# c++ alignment of struct with aligned members

Tags: c++, struct, memory-alignment

Is a `struct` always aligned the same as the largest-alignment member of that struct? If not, how can this be enforced automatically, perhaps using a gcc-specific extension? (I know there is `__attribute((aligned(...)))__`, but the alignment has to be specified explicitly).

Does this behavior differ between c99, c++99 and c++11? Does c++11 have some extra provisions for enforcing alignment?

**EXAMPLE:**
With the following code, will `Foo` itself be automatically aligned to 8 bytes, or do I need to align it explicitly as well?

```
struct Foo{
    int i __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

Comment: @Basile: I added the example, that should make it clear.

Comment: The alignment of a compound type is indeed the alignment of its largest member. Think about arrays of those types!

Comment: Why do you worry about alignment? Compilers usually do a good enough job about it!

Comment: @Basile: I get crashes when types which must be aligned (packet math) are allocated in at non-aligned addresses. (You can safely assume I have a good reason to ask when I ask)

Comment: @KerrekSB: can you give some reference to what you say and write is as answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB: I was confused by http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/api/TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html where alignment of the containing struct must be enforced via an overloaded new-operator.

Comment: You should have told that you are using dynamic allocation. Then the alignment burden is on the allocator function. I improved my reply accordingly.

Comment: @eudoxos: I don't think it's in the standard directly, but it follows essentially from the fact that each member must be aligned correctly, and this must hold even for arrays of the compound type, and the array must consist of contiguous storage. Of course you could simply implement this by padding *every* type up to `sizeof(max_align_t)` and just giving every type maximal alignment, but since stricter alignments also satisfy weaker ones, it's reasonable to expect that a struct will just have the maximal alignment among its members.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment is a system and processor specific property. The compiler is permitted to do its best (and has to know about the alignment constraints of the processor and of the system).

Most ABI specifications (e.g. [AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) for Linux) contain some alignment hints.

I do believe that alignment constraints are propagated from fields to aggregates (e.g. `struct`-s) containing them.

If you have unusual alignment constraints for dynamically allocated data, you might need to explicit the alignment, e.g. by using [posix_memalign](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign) to allocate them. [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and related allocators (including `::operator new` in C++) probably won't align better than what the default constraints require.